# Get a count of distinct rows that does not include a value in any row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has multiple rows for the same ID. I need to return a count of the distinct IDs which have no rows that contain a value. I have tried something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT studID) AS 'ID' 
    FROM all_classes WHERE absences=0 
    AND (SELECT DISTINCT studID 
        FROM all_classes 
        WHERE absences<>0)
    <>studID;
```

In this example, I am trying to write a query to find the number of students who have zero absences in all classes. If they have an absence in one class but zero in the other classes, they should be ignored (which is what I am using the nested query for, but it doesn't work). Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were very close.  I would have used a NOT IN subquery.  And I don't think the first where criteria was necessary.

This should pull any student id where all rows of the id have absences=0

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT studID) AS 'ID' 
FROM all_classes WHERE studID NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT studID 
    FROM all_classes 
    WHERE absences<>0);
```

Comment: That worked! Funny what a small change does. And you were correct about the first WHERE criteria, it didn't change anything when I took it out of the query I'm working on. Thank you!

Comment: No problem.  Also look at @David answer about using exists vs in.  You should use exists instead of in.  Quite frankly it just hasn't bit me yet so I forget about it.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to rewrite your query is like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT studID) AS 'ID' -- 'total students' makes more sense?
FROM all_classes
WHERE studID NOT IN(
    SELECT studID 
    FROM all_classes 
    WHERE absences <> 0
)
```

However, when you're not actually selecting something using a subquery it's better to use exists:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT studID) AS 'ID'
FROM all_classes a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM all_classes a1 
    WHERE a1.studID = a.studID 
    AND absences > 0 -- I assume absences can't be negative
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be as simple as this:

```
SELECT Count(studID) AS IDCount
FROM all_classes
GROUP BY studID
HAVING SUM(absences) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Is all you want is a head count of students with no absences this should work.

```
select Count(*) 
from all_classes 
group by stud_id 
having sum(absences)=0
```

This would give you the studid of the students in question.

```
select studid
from all_classes 
group by stud_id 
having sum(absences)=0
```